# Tomcat 7 service ignores shutdown timeout setting

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, service, timeout

I installed Apache Tomcat 7.0.70 on a Windows 7 machine as a service and I set shutdown timeout to 30 secs as seen in the picture below:

[image]

I started the service, works like it should, everything is fine.
But when I stop the service it takes a minute to stop, although I set the timeout to 30 secs. After several tests I found out that the timeout setting is irrelevant in this case as the service needs always 60 secs to stop no matter what timeout value I set. Below is a snippet from the log, it clearly shows that the service was stopping for a minute exactly:

[image]

I suspected an OS setting behind this penomenon but I find nothing about it.

Did anybody ever experience something similar?